# On the econometric notation of conditional expectation.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, notation, expectation

I have recently studied probability theory and I know the definition of conditional expectation, going back on some econometric notes I am unsure on some notation.

Say we have $X,Y$ random variables defined on a probability space then my econometric notes say:

$$E[X| Y] = \hat{X} = \int x P(x|Y) \,dx$$

What does the notation $P(x|Y)$ stand for?

Does it refers to the probability density of the conditional expectation ? it can't be he conditional expectation of the indicator function of the event $X^{-1}(x)$, correct?

Now say we have another AC r.v. $V$ with density $P_V$ and that the relation $X = Y+V$ holds

then the econometric notes say

$$\int xP(x|Y) \,dx = \int x P_V ( x- y) \,dx $$

I don't understand how a change of density took place, have we used Radon-Nikodim? Could somebody provide some rigor to these manipulations?

Comment: a hint for next time there is a notation tag for questions on notation ( okay more about math notation so technicality.).

Answer (score 1):

I believe that $P(x | Y)$ is a random probability density function whose value is (or *becomes*) $P(X = x | Y = y)$ when $Y = y$. This intuitive explanation suffices to understand the integral.

Put differently (if additional formalism helps), $P(x | Y)$ is a function from outcomes involving $Y$ to probability density functions over $X$. This can be written as $P : Y \rightarrow (\wp(\Omega) \rightarrow [0,1])$.

Your text is playing a bit fast and loose with notation, but if we have $X = Y + V \Rightarrow V = X - Y$, and if $Y = y$ is known, then we can apply a form of [convolution of probability density functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_of_probability_distributions). The key insight is that $P(X = x, Y = y) = P(Y = y, X - Y = x - y)$ (you can convince yourself of this using a set-theoretic argument with diagrams), from which we have $P(X - Y = x - y | Y = y) P(Y = y)$ by the definition of conditional probability.

In this case, we can write:
$$P(X = x | Y = y) = \frac{P(X = x, Y = y)}{P(Y = y)} = \frac{P(X - Y = x - y | Y = y) P(Y = y)}{P(Y = y)} = P(V = x - y | Y = y)$$

This gives us:
$$ \int x P_{X | Y}(x | Y) dx = \int x \frac{P_{X,Y}(x,y)}{P_{Y}(y)} dx = \int x \frac{P_{V | Y}(V = x - y | Y = y) P_{Y}(y)}{P_{Y}(y)} dx = \int x P_{V | Y}(x - y | y) dx$$

If we know $Y = y$, this becomes simply $\int x P_{V}(x - y) dx$.

*Edit: various notational corrections*

Comment: I understand the set theoretic argument but I am unsure if it applies to densities, in other words to prove this $f_{(X,Y)}(x,y) = f_{(Y,X-Y)} (y,x-y)$ I would need to calculate the convolution $X-Y$ and then try to recuperate the joint density, I have tried but I don't think it is possible.

Comment: Without knowing the specifics of where you're stuck or what you're trying to prove this of in particular, I'm not sure how best to help you. There's a little more explanation of convolution [here](https://math.la.asu.edu/~jtaylor/teaching/Fall2010/STP421/lectures/lecture20.pdf).

Comment: I do $f_{X-Y}(z) = \int_{- \infty}^{+\infty} f_X(t) f_{-Y} (z-t) \,dt $ and then I am stuck because I don't know a way to find the joint density $f_{(Y,X-Y)} (y,x-y)$.

Comment: I don't believe that's right. It's not your fault, though. Convolution is somewhat challenging.

Try and proceed along the lines of my rewriting probability statements and integrals. The solution is as the last line of my answer indicates, which coincides with your book:
$$\int x P_V(x-y) dx$$
The important upshot is that you can write $\int x P_{X|Y}(x|Y) dx$, which typically depends on $X$ and $Y$, as a function of simply $y$ if you know the density function of $V = X - Y$.